# Merging Two Lists Error

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am writing a function *merge(L1,L2)* that takes two list inputs and merges them. However, when I run it, I get an error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'** Can someone help me?

```
def merge(L1,L2):
  T = []
  subscript = 0
  while len(L1) > 0 and len(L2) > 0:
      if L1[subscript] < L2[subscript]:
        T.append(str(L1[subscript])) + "," + str(L2[subscript])
      elif L1[subscript] == L2[subscript]:
        del L2[subscript]
        T.append(L1[subscript])
      elif L1[subscript] > L2[subscript]:
        T.append(str(L2[subscript])) + "," + str(L1[subscript])
      subscript += 1
  return T

# print merge([0,2,4,6,8] , [1,3,5,7]) should return [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
# I`m assuming that the input lists are sorted.
```

Comment: Why not add and __then__ sort

Comment: Think about what the error means. And then maybe print the values you have between `+`

Comment: take a look at the parens in lines with `T.append`

Comment: The line with the error should be `T.extend([L1[subscript], L2[subscript]])` Next, learn what a "type" is, and the difference between an integer, a string and a list.

Comment: the next error you get is an IndexError

Comment: Why are you trying to remove an item from `L2`?

Comment: In the result, I do not want duplicates.

Comment: The result is a new list `T`. Unless you add an item twice, `T` will not have duplicates. Whether or not you leave the item in `L2` makes no difference (and for someone using your code, they may be surprised why one of the input lists was modified).

Comment: Also, learn about lists in Python. Just because a comma is used to *display* the list doesn't mean the list actually *contains* commas, and that you need to add the commas to `T` when building it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proper merge (although not the best way to actually write it, it matches your approach):

```
def merge(L1, L2):
    T = []
    subscript1 = 0
    subscript2 = 0
    while len(L1) > subscript1 and len(L2) > subscript2:
        if L1[subscript1] < L2[subscript2]:
            T.append(L1[subscript1])
            subscript1 += 1
        elif L1[subscript1] == L2[subscript2]:
            T.append(L1[subscript1])
            subscript1 += 1
            subscript2 += 1
        elif L1[subscript1] > L2[subscript2]:
            T.append(L2[subscript2])
            subscript2 += 1
    T.extend(L1[subscript1:])
    T.extend(L2[subscript2:])
    return T
```

You don't add commas directly to `T`; they are just used when displaying `T`. Rather, you simply add to `T` the smaller of the two current elements from `L1` and `L2`. If both are the same size, you only add it once. Each time you add an element from `L1` or `L2` (or both), you increment the appropriate subscript. Once you exhaust one list, you just add the remaining items from the other to the end of `T`. (Notice that you don't have to check which list is finished; extending `T` with an empty list is a no-op.)